# Obtaining regular raster grid from netCDF format grid data in ArcGIS Desktop or R?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, netcdf, climate

I downloaded `E-OBS` gridded data from European climate data assessment ([grid datasets website](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/downloadchunks.php) and [dataset 1](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.25deg_reg/tg_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc.gz) and [dataset 2](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.25deg_reg/tg_0.25deg_reg_1995-2010_v17.0.nc.gz)), and I am interested in 0.25 degree grid data of land surface temperature and precipitation for Germany only, but E-OBS grid data is conducted on whole Europe and all measurement in daily level. However, this grid datasets were divided and each chunk has 15 years climate data observation, and I need 30 years data. So I downloaded two big `.nc` file from this site, but this file is quite big. I want to read those in `ArcGIS desktop` as raster and intend to pull out Germany. So I did these in `ArcGIS`:

from `Multidimension Tool.tbx` -> `Make NetCDF Feature Layer`, to see its attribute table of those grid data in `ArcGis`, but I have only coordinate pair while respective daily temperature observations' attribute table is not shown. Here is the screenshot of reading `.nc` file as `raster` in ArcGIS:

```
+-----+-------------+------------+------------+
| FID |  longitude  |  latitude  |     tg     |
+-----+-------------+------------+------------+
|   1 | -14.6250000 | 25.3750000 | 17.3799992 |
|   2 | -14.3750000 | 25.3750000 | 17.3799992 |
|   3 | -14.1250000 | 25.3750000 | 17.3500004 |
|   4 | -13.8750000 | 25.3750000 | 17.2899990 |
|   5 | -13.6250000 | 25.3750000 | 17.3400002 |
|   6 | -13.3750000 | 25.3750000 | 17.3299999 |
|   7 | -13.1250000 | 25.3750000 | 16.9400005 |
|   8 | -12.8750000 | 25.3750000 | 16.7600002 |
|   9 | -12.6250000 | 25.3750000 | 16.4300003 |
|  10 | -12.3750000 | 25.3750000 | 16.1099987 |
|  11 | -12.1250000 | 25.3750000 | 15.8699999 |
|  12 | -11.8750000 | 25.3750000 | 15.7500000 |
|  13 | -11.6250000 | 25.3750000 | 16.1299992 |
+-----+-------------+------------+------------+
```

**Desired output**:

I want to make raster grid from this `.nc` file and want to have attribute table where grid node' coordinate with respective daily temperature observations.

I am not familiar with working `.nc` files in R, so I want to read those `netCDF` file in `ArcGIS` and want to get raster grid first, then crop all grids of Germany where geo-coordinate must come along with respective daily temperature observation.

How can I make this happen in `ArcGIS`?

How can I convert grid data in `.nc` file to regular raster grid in `ArcGIS`?

Can anyone help me how to get this done easily in geospatial software tools?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question. I think you should start by deciding which of ArcGIS Desktop and R you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: Short answer is `library(raster); r <- raster("file.nc"); as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE)` - longer answer is see `?raster` and `?crop`